# R - How to change the width of a column in a gtable

Tags: r, ggplot2, grob, gtable

I am creating a gtable consisting of 3 x ggplot grobs using cbind, but I would like to make the middle column less wide than the 1st and 3rd column. How would I go about doing this?

The centre column only contains text so does not need equal width to the other columns containing charts:

```
library(grid)

# get ggplot grob
p4grob <- ggplotGrob(p4)
gdp4grob <- ggplotGrob(gdp4)
labels4grob <- ggplotGrob(labels4)
gt = cbind(gdp4grob, labels4grob, p4grob)


grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image: A chart showing a 3 column gtable created using the R programming language]

Many thanks!

Comment: While I appreciate your effort I would suggest to have a look at `gridExtra::grid.arrange` or `patchwork` or `cowplot`. Using `gridExtra::grid.arrange` you could do `gridExtra::grid.arrange(p4, labels4, gdp4, widths = c(2, 1, 2), nrow = 1`.

Comment: Thank @stefan. grid.arrange looks very promising. The only problem is that the second column is aligning to the bottom of the column, meaning it's out of alignment. I'm digging around to find if there's an alignment option but no luck so far. Do you happen to know how this could be done (i.e. align the contents of each column to the top)?

Comment: For now I did a bit of a hack and just reinstated the x-axis labels and text and made them white so the chart was the same height, but not ideal.

Comment: Personally I prefer using `patchwork` as in my experience it does the best job when it comes to aligning the plots. But even with patchwork I think your hack is the way that I would have suggested, too.

Answer (score 0):

Good suggestion in comments to use `gridExtra`. Much easier. But, as mentioned, I still had to do a couple of simple hacks to ensure the 3 x ggplots aligned properly, because `grid.arrange` bottom-aligns the content of a column (a bit odd and I didn't overcome this).

My resulting `grid.arrange` code is as-follows, and totally moves away from using extracted grobs and cbind and leaves it to `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`

````
```{r, fig.show='hide'}
library(grid)

# Prepare custom pyramid plot
g <- gridExtra::grid.arrange(NULL,
                        gdp4, 
                        labels4, 
                        p4, 
                        NULL,
                        widths = c(0.1,2,0.65,2,0.1), 
                        nrow = 1, 
                        top = textGrob(
                          'Top 10 Waste Generating Coastal Nations By Region\nPlastic Waste vs GDP Per Capita',
                          gp=gpar(col="white"),
                        ),
                        padding = unit(1, "cm")
                        )
````

Note that I actually created 5 columns, with the left-most and right-most columns being `NULL`, just because the output was cropping the numbers in the x-axis, and that was how I added a small amount of padding to the chart.

Also, obviously a few additional features used working towards the final product (e.g. don't confuse `padding` with padding the overall chart/grid/table because it is just padding the title).

I also ended up using `cowplot` to adjust the theme of the resulting variable from `grid.arrange`, explaining the change in appearance to blue background (and a few other alterations were done in `ggplot2` prior to final product, so the change in appearance is not resulting from using `grid.arrange()`).

````
```{r fig.align="center", fig.height = 10, fig.width = 10}
# Format and output chart
g2 <- cowplot::ggdraw(g) + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#172f52"),
        )

plot(g2)
````

Also note that I added `fig.hide` for the original R Markdown chunk because I couldn't stop `grid.arrange()` from outputting the chart, even when I was assigning it to a variable, so had to hide it via R Markdown tags, and then put the `cowplot` plot in a separate chunk for output.

[image]